# Typescript react/redux guide - how to translate from js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-redux

I'm translating from this [guide](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#components-todo-js). Here is the code I've translated so far(inside Todo.tsx):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as PropTypes from 'react';

interface ITodo
{
  onClick : ()=>void,
  completed : boolean,
  text : string
}
​
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text } : ITodo) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={ {
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
)
```

However I'm struggling with the second part (in js:)

```
Todo.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Since `PropTypes` doesn't seem to contain any of the `bool` or `func` or `string` members.

Comment: You definitely should not rename to a new namespace all exports from a package. You should avoid using `*` when you can IMO

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff What do you suggest to use instead - I reckon importing specific namespace but what specific namespace to import from `React`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's virtually no reason to be using PropTypes with TypeScript.

Secondly, you may want to consider enabling `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` or the more recent addition whose name escapes me to your `tsconfig.json` so that you can avoid having to `import * as`.

Thirdly, you should be defining your SFC as a `React.SFC`, rather than asserting the expected props in the argument. As follows:

```
const Todo: React.SFC<ITodo> = (props) => ();
```

You can of course destructure and use JSX as you were doing.

Comment: Why is using `React.SFC` better?

Comment: I've set the flag you specified - `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` but can you explain to me how ths help avoiding the `import * as` - what else should I wrote? Anyway I think I got it - `import React from 'react'`.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff It's idiomatic, so at a glance you know you're working with a React SFC. It also defines `children` for you. These aren't big enough reasons to warrant going back and changing everything you've ever done otherwise, however I would recommend using `React.SFC` going forward.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions You got it. Here are the TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Thank you! @SamHH

Answer (score 1):

Replace `import * as PropTypes from 'react';` with `import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: How does that even compiles?

Comment: In the newer version or `React` PropTypes live in its own package `prop-types`. It is not in the `react` package anymore

Comment: but that 'd be better `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as PropTypes from 'react';
```

These two lines are strange and I am not sure they are working. `React` and `PropTypes` are the default export of their own package. So if you are using React `v15.5` and above it should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

if you are using a lower version of React would could also do:

`import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';`

**On your `TypeScript` question:**

You can remove the `propTypes` declaration, as you are already typing your component with `TypeScript` using the `interface` you declared. Hence `propTypes` become useless.

You still can use `defaultProps` if one of your props is optional

Comment: What is `defaultProps`?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Nothing really related to your questions but an important React concept nonetheless. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)